# How to make autocomplete_fields search in model's string representation in Django 3

Tags: python, django, django-admin

As I am using string representation of a model, it is also shown in a autocomplete_fields (Select2). But the problem is that when i try to search in the field, it is searching the model's name field, not string representation.
Here is my code example:

**models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)



class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Shelf(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __string__(self):
        return f'{self.department.store.name} {self.department.name} {self.name}'

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    shelf = models.ForeignKey(Shelf, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ('shelf',)
    list_display = ('name', 'shelf')
```

Is it posible to search by model string representation in this case?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your string method should be `__str__` instead and since the str method is not a field you cannot add it to the autocomplete field since it looks for a field and works on the DB level.
What you can do is:

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ('shelf__department__store__name','shelf__department__name','name')
    list_display = ('name', 'shelf')
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I've tried it and i get an error `The value of 'autocomplete_fields[0]' refers to 'shelf__department__store__name', which is not an attribute of 'Product'`

Comment: I would say your best bet would be using dal_admin_filter or django autocomplete light filter which will allow you the max flexibility. there you can adjust search feature at your expense by over writing queryset method and span search feature to as many fields as you like.